# Is the Context passed into the Mapper functions (setup,map,run,cleanup) always the same?

Tags: java, hadoop

1. Is the same Context passed in to setup ,map, run, cleanup within the
   Mapper?
2. Will there be a case where its not the same?
3. Can you make the context a member field within the setup?

[Mapper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes inside the *same* mapper it is the one and same *context* object in `setup()`,`map()` and `cleanup()`.

As you may see these methods are called from the `run()`, and that method goes like follows:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
      map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
    cleanup(context);
  }
```

That should answer your points 1 and 2, and for point 3, you can override the run method to have more control as it's Javadoc suggests:

> Expert users can override this method for more complete control over
>   the execution of the Mapper.

And perhaps you do not need to keep a member field for context, but sure you can.

Also, while the object is same, it's properties' values mat be set or unset in any of the methods making it to be in a different state than it was when passed to another method (setup,map or cleanup).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for [Mapper.Context](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.Context.html). Given a particular job, some of the attributes like `getJobID()` remains the same, while some of the attributes like `getInputSplit()` might be different across maps within the same job.